# From Object to dayJs

Tags: javascript, dayjs

Is it possible to create a `dayjs` with and `Object`?.

For example, in moment we have.

```
   let newDate = moment({years:2000,months:1,days:1})
```

which will create a `moment` date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is possible since the **version 1.8.26**, for doing this you need a [plugin](https://unpkg.com/browse/dayjs@1.8.27/plugin/) wich you install on your needs.

Here's a little example on how to do it, in case you want to implement it on the browser

```js
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_objectSupport)
let x = dayjs({
  year: 2010,
  month: 1,
  day: 12
})

console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.36/plugin/objectSupport.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.36/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```